# How to test differences between coefficients of determination R²?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have two sample Models M1 and M2 and a time series with 1000 observations of x, B, C and D. M1 is a nested model of M2.

```
M1: x = a + b1*B + b2*C

M2: x = z + y1*B + y2*C + y2*D
```

I regress now both models to get two different coefficients of determination R².

```
M1: R²M1 = 0.68
M2: R²M2 = 0.70
```

I calculate the difference of them.

```
R²M2-R²M1 = 0.70-0.68 = 0.02
```

How can I test now this difference between the coefficients of determination R²?

I tried the Meng test, but it seems to lack something.

german: http://www.andre-hahn.de/Statistik/Korrelationsdifferenz.html;

english: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37867-meng-s-z-test-for-correlated-correlation-coefficients

I simulate similiar regressions like in the example 100.000 times, but I don't get 5% significant results for a 5% normal distributed test statistic. (which I expected to be logical and assumable).

I am also quite sure, that I cannot use a simple t-test to test the difference against zero due to the correlated correlations nature of both R² of the nested models.

Do you know any test for differences in the coefficients of determination R² between two nested models?

Comment: Your notation is confusing. You mention A is a nested model of B, define models A and B, but then you have B in you model for B.. Please update your question - eg use $M_1$ for Model 1 and $M_2$ for model 2

Comment: @unseen_rider I've improved the notation like suggest.

Comment: Your models look nested to me, why not use ANOVA F-test??

Comment: Are you attempting to compare the models to determine whether $y_2$ is significant, or are you truly interested in the *population* $R^2$ (as suggested by the language you are using)?  If it's the latter, then something is strange, because two models *of the same thing* will necessarily have identical values of the population $R^2$!  If it's the former, then comparing $R^2$ is a bad procedure: use a standard test such as the F-test in an ANOVA.

Comment: Note that, usually in multiple regression, $R^2$ is **not** a population parameter.  It depends also on the design of the experiment. Exceptions are cases when the predictors really is a sample from some population, not designed.

Comment: @whuber What about testing for sample $R^2$? I *think* that's the question.

Comment: @Small That would make no sense: tests apply to *parameters* of a supposed population or distribution.  The sample statistic is whatever it is--but there is nothing to test about it.  Yet, one could use the sample $R^2$ to test a hypothesis about a parameter, such as $D$.  However, using a difference of sample $R^2$ is not the way to go about it.  The right way would be equivalent to an $F$ test.